# Version 4 ICC Profiles were converted to version 2 ICC Profiles during PDF Export error Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, color-profile, error

### Version 4 ICC Profiles were converted to version 2 ICC Profiles during PDF Export error Indesign

---

**Context:**

---

I am currently trying to export a file from Indesign into a PDF, however, I am getting the following errors:

```
Version 4 ICC Profiles were converted to version 2 ICC Profiles during PDF Export.
```

Followed by:

```
Failed to Export the PDF file.
```

I looked this up and came across [this forum on Adobe](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/version-4-icc-profiles-were-converted-to-version-2-icc-profiles-during-pdf-export/td-p/10327192?page=1) help centre. Following the answers on there, I isolated the issue to Page 5 (which has a number of images). However, the forum suggested the problem was having an RGB image on a CMYK, but all my images on my file seem to be RGB (No CMYK) and since there is only an issue with one page, this must not be the issue.

---

**Question**

---

Does anybody know why this error keeps happening? How can I fix it or if need be override it to create the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the color profile your images have I can't go into details with what is going on, but often when stuff like happens a quick and dirty fix might be to somehow save the files again.

If you can open the images in Photoshop, try to do this with each of them:

- Open the image in Photoshop.
- Convert the image to another RGB color profile like Adobe RGB.
- Save the image.
- Update the image in InDesign.

If that doesn't help there might be some strange file corruption going on. In that case it might be helpful to copy/paste each image into a new document of the same size, save them and relink in InDesign.

*BTW: Having RGB images in a CMYK document is a perfectly normal thing and isn't the cause of  the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

I found that when exporting, I had selected none for convert to profile. Once I changed to convert to destination I had no issues.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/113337)